# Where´s the Issue with the EOF line?

Tags: bash, heredoc

I´ve changed from SuSE to RHEL and trying to us same code, I´m geting some error related with identation, I believe. SuSE was using bash3 and RHEL it´s using bash4.

Error message:

```
-bash: test.sh: line 9: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
-bash: test.sh: line 21: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

When I change:

```
    EOF)
```

For this (remove the tab):

```
EOF)
```

works fine. I understand the issue, but I would like to understand why it´s working fine with SuSE and RHEL it´s not. The point is that change this in the code will take a really big time and work, so is there any way to workaround this with unix session, or some config?

```
#!/bin/bash
    result=$(sqlplus -S /nolog  << EOF
        WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;
        Connect $ORACLE_USER/$(sh /bin/encrypt.sh -d "$ORACLE_PASS")@${HOST}:${PORT}/${HOST}
        set heading off
        set line 1000
        $QUERY;
        EXIT;
        EOF)
    result=$(echo $result | tail --lines=1)
    echo $result
    return $result
}
```

Comment: Re: "change this in the code will take a really big time and work": That surprises me. How many heredocs can your script possibly have?

Comment: do you use tabs or spaces for indentation ? also, have a look at the `-EOF` option for heredocs

Comment: The `)` on the same line may also be an issue.

Comment: You have an errant `}`, though it's not causing the problem. Also most of the script is indented one level too much. Looks like you copied this from a function definition, eh?

Comment: Also, `return` isn't supposed to return a value (even if you are computing a value between 0 and 255); it's supposed to provide an *exit status*. Your script would appear to be in desperate need of rewriting anyway, so I wouldn't bother with any workarounds. Fix your script.

Comment: @ruakh - there´s a lot, and the point is also that my DEV team don´t want to change. "it was working before, so should work like this".

Comment: @chepner you´re right. I think the best solution here is to fix the script (dev team). I was just thinking somethin glike: "ok, I can do this meanwhile, but you need to fix", but we know that this way they will never fix. :)

Comment: One more question, is this related with the bash4 version? As I said, it´s working same code in SuSE with bash3.

Comment: No, bash 3 didn't allow `<<EOF`-style heredocs to be indented either (even then, it had to be `<<-EOF` to allow any indentation at all, and even that only allows tabs with no spaces).

Comment: As for your dev team's "it should work like this" -- when you don't write things to the language specification, you have no promise of forwards compatibility; if the only reason something looks like it works is that it passes your tests, you don't know if it works because it's operating to-spec, or if it "works" only narrowly or because of a bug.

Comment: ...in particular, bash promises compliance with the POSIX sh specification (with extensions in undefined space), so if POSIX says something is explicitly disallowed, bash is buggy when it allows it, and future versions can be expected to fix that bug (except for some corner cases like `echo -e` where bash's mantainership intentionally decided to be noncompliant).

Comment: One relevant change between `bash` 3 and 4 is that `bash` 3 is more lenient about a here document being terminated by the end of the input file (which in this case is induced by the command substitution). `bash` 4 is more insistent that the here document be properly terminated before the file ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to indent the here-doc delimiter, you should change `<<` to `<<-`. You must use tabs to indent your code, spaces do not work. Note that `)` doesn't follow the `EOF`; that's because bash can't close the `$()` otherwise.

```
VAL=$(cat <<-EOF
        derp
        EOF
)
echo "$VAL"
exit 0
```